# How to show alert dialog box only once in a day in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm working on an app in which I want to add a functionality that shows an alert dialog box ***only once a day*** when the user opens the app. I'm done with the dialog box I used the `boolean variable` if this bool value is `true` then show *dialog* else don't show the *dialog*. Once the dialog opens on tap of the button I set the `bool value to false`. But my question is how it will set `true` again at the `end of the day?` What should I need to do so the bool value again set to true at the end of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a boolean, you need the last date/time the dialog was shown.

Every time a situation occurs in which you may need to show the dialog, you get the current date/time now and compare that with date/time of the last dialog showing.

Because you can't be sure if the app will be killed or now, you also need to store the last date/time the app was shown on disk.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the last access time of the user with [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and check if the user was using the app today.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('lastAccess', DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch)

    // Get last access
    final int lastAccess = prefs.getInt('lastAccess');

    if(lastAccess!=null){
      // Get last access as DateTime
      final DateTime lastAccessTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(lastAccess);

      // Check if he opened the app
      final opened = lastAccessTime.isAfter(DateTime.now());

      if(!opened){
        // Show Dialog
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the easiest algorithm.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int? lastDay = prefs.getInt('lastDay');
    int today = DateTime.now().day;
    if (lastDay == null || lastDay != today) {
      //Show the dialog
      prefs.setInt('lastDay', today);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
timer = Timer.periodic(
 Duration(days: 1,), 
 (Timer t) => {
  //callback
 });
```

Comment: The timer is also running when the app is in the background?

Comment: hmm, search the flutter docs for if its running in the background or not